# BCP queryout images stored in varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, encoding, bcp

I am replacing a .net app that pulled records out of a database using a `SqlDataReader`. I am replacing it with two part process where SQL Server will `BCP queryout` the data from a `varbinary(max)` column to a flat file and a .net app will consume the flat files to create .jpg images from each row from a `byte[]` that is in the `varbinary(max)` column.

The existing code simply cast the column into a byte array using:

```
(byte[])reader[field];
```

In my case I am trying  to use:

```
System.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringFromFlatFile)
```

but the resulting file cannot be viewed on a Windows machine (error damaged/corrupted, or too large)

I have tried every one of the encoding types under System.Encoding (Ascii, UTFX, etc..) with no luck.

Is there an extra step in `BCP queryout` I need take to keep preserve byte array in the `varbinary(max)` column? Is there anything special `SqlDataReader` is doing to return the byte array that I need to add to the .net app?

Comment: Look at the code that puts the binary jpg into the filed.  That may give you a clue.   Does BCP query out create a string representation of the bytes.  So it would have a string "0x659671"  instead of the bytes of numeric value 65 96 71 .    Also if you have existing code reading from that field look at it.

Comment: I do not have access to how the data was put into the table, but agree you are on the right track. I created a test method that uses a data reader to pull the image into a bytearray from the varbinary field. I then used a memory stream of the byte array for a System. I then used a System.Drawing.Image to save as a jpg. The image is viewable in windows. I then used every encoding method available to create a string from the byte array. None of them look anything like the string created by bcp.

Comment: Bcp creates a string that looks like "FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB00430....".

Comment: Started a related but more specific thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266451/how-does-bcp-queryout-encode-varbinarymax-and-can-i-change-the-encoding

Comment: Found one approach that works.. but it is only one image/row at a time:
http://madhuottapalam.blogspot.com/2008/08/creating-files-from-images-stored-in.html   I would still like to be able to do a bach of rows instead of using a cursor.

Comment: Tested the approach with a cursor (one image at a time). It is far to slow for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this more as reference that might lead you to a solution in your specific situation.

This has worked for me 24x7x365 for 8 years.

**I want to point out that a string conversion or encode is never used**.  The bytes always stay as bytes.

This is VB.Net code

```
' The following code has run untouched for 6 years and gets images for me from the DB
' You may be able to see a detail that is relavent to you 
' NOTE The field binary read is by numeric field number - not by field name string
'      Notice the the buffer is grabbed in chunks into the buffer - not all at once 
'      Notice the CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess modifier
'
' There is no "conversion" of bytes thorugh any casting going on with encoding
' The bytes are left untouched 
'
' At the end is the snippit I use to write out the file to disk


Dim filledByteArray As Byte()
    filledByteArray = Nothing

Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand 
Dim drNewPdf As SqlDataReader

            cn.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionStringHere"

            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandText = "myStoredProcWithOneOftheFieldsIsBinary"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            ' notice the command behavior argument
            cn.Open()
            drNewPdf = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

            If drNewPdf.HasRows Then

                While drNewPdf.Read

            imgIdInt = drNewPdf.Item("FldNameOfInternalIntegerIdField")

                    ' - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - -  -
                    ' Read the Binary Field Here
                    ' - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - -  -


                    Dim ms As MemoryStream                 ' Writes the BLOB to a file (*.bmp).
                    Dim bw As BinaryWriter               ' Streams the binary data to the FileStream object.

                    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 100      ' The size of the BLOB buffer.
                    Dim outbyte(bufferSize - 1) As Byte  ' The BLOB byte() buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
                    Dim retval As Long                   ' The bytes returned from GetBytes.
                    Dim startIndex As Long = 0           ' The starting position in the BLOB output.



                    ' Create a stream to hold the output.
                    ms = New MemoryStream()
                    bw = New BinaryWriter(ms)

                    ' Reset the starting byte for a new BLOB.
                    startIndex = 0

                    ' READ THE FIELD HERE !!!! And Below in the loop
                    '5  '"ImageFieldBLOB"

                    ' Read bytes into outbyte() and retain the number of bytes returned.
                    retval = drNewPdf.GetBytes(5, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize)

                    ' Continue reading and writing while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
                    Do While retval = bufferSize
                        bw.Write(outbyte)
                        bw.Flush()

                        ' Reposition the start index to the end of the last buffer and fill the buffer.
                        startIndex += bufferSize

                        ' READ THE FIELD HERE !!!!  And Above in the loop
                        '5 is the field index into the recordset - use field id 5 in this case 
                        ' Read bytes into outbyte() and retain the number of bytes returned.
                        retval = drNewPdf.GetBytes(5, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize)
                    Loop

                    ' Write the remaining buffer.
                    bw.Write(outbyte, System.Convert.ToInt32(0L), System.Convert.ToInt32(retval))
                    bw.Flush()


                    streamLEN = System.Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length)

                    filledByteArray = New Byte(streamLEN - 1) {}
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                    ms.Read(filledByteArray, 0, streamLEN)


                    ' Close the output file.
                    bw.Close()
                    ms.Close()


                    ' - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - -  -
                    ' End the Binary Field Read - Loop to next record -
                    ' - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - -  -
                End While
            Else
                'No Rows ?

            End If


            cn.Close()
            cn.Dispose()





 ' A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT CHUNK OF CODE FOR PHYSICALLY WRITING TO DISK
            Dim outFileStream As FileStream

            outFileStream = New FileStream(selectedFileInfo.FullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

            outFileStream.Write(byteArrayFromDb, 0, byteArrayFromDb.Length)

            outFileStream.Flush()

            outFileStream.Close()
```

**My main point is that there is never a string conversion to bytes.**

Comment: Thank you for posting, but I already have something similar working in c#. My hope was to use bcp to speed the process, it may turn out not to be the ideal approach.